# Action to element with same id

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to call a function on items with the same Id with Jquery.
I tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').each(function(){
        this.dataTable();
    });
} );
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5tz6bk6w/)

Answer (score 2):

IDs should be unique. use class and class selectors instead.

```
$('.example').each(function(){
    $(this).dataTable();
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/n3tn78hd/)**

Answer (score 2):

First of all, ID should be unique. So, use class instead of id.

Next thing you should bind the jquery to use the method:

```
$(this).dataTable(); // instead of this, use $(this)
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.example').each(function(){
        $(this).dataTable();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`Id`s can't be same ,they must be `unique`

you should use `class` instead of `id`

so

if you give `class="example"` for all your required elements then you could use

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.example').each(function(){
        $(this).dataTable();
    });
});
```